# Image resizing in WordPress fails when image dimensions are over approximately 4200 x 4200

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the [**Simple Local Avatars**](http://pastebin.com/kXTu5HA2) plugin. I'm having trouble with certain images. The problem seems to relate to image dimensions rather than image file size.

Images are uploaded no matter what file size or dimensions they are. This is the 'full' or original image.

My problem seems to happen when new file sizes are generated by the `get_avatar()` function. I've pasted the `get_avatar` function that is used in the plugin [**here**](http://pastebin.com/kXTu5HA2) for reference. If the 'full' image is less than around 4200 x 4200 in dimensions then the resizing works. However, if the dimensions are bigger than that, let's say 5200 x 5200 then the resizing fails. No resized image is generated in the `/uploads/` folder and no resized value is recorded to the `simple_local_avatars` key in the user meta table.

You can see in the `get_avatar` function, `wp_get_image_editor()` is used to do the resizing.

What could the problem be and how can I solve it?

Comment: Anything in the log file?

Comment: a 4200x4200 24bit color image requires ~52 megabytes of memory once it's loaded into GD... Your script is undoubtedly failing with an out-of-memory error, and you've got all logging/error display options turned off so you never get told this. 5200x5200@24bit requires ~81 megs.

Comment: i've just checked my memory limit using `phpinfo()` and it's set at `120M` - this _should_ be enough for 5200 x 5200?

Answer (score -1):

I should be an out of memory error.

Try this on the beginning of the script:

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit','128M');

#and display errors to see whats happening

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

#rest of the code goes here

?>
```

if your server allows to change the memory limit, it should work.

Comment: thanks for the info @pbs - my memory_limit is already set to 120M so I don't think this is a memory issue?